# Is it possible to setup Approval Process and Steps via Data Loader?

Tags: data-loader

I have list of approval process and steps which are large in number(600). I have the data ready with all the details. I know that we can move data using DataLoader. But, is it possible to do the setup as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approval Processes and Steps form part of your orgs Setup data and as such are exposed via the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) (as apposed to standard objects), while its actually a good idea to do so, currently the Data Loader does not support this API, so you cannot use it for this.

If you can translate your data into the XML format shown in this help topic for the [ApprovalProcess Metadata type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_approvalprocess.htm), you can use the [Salesforce Migration Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/) (a command line tool powered by Apache Ant) to upload them. Or alternatively if you have programming skills you can write a Java program to read your files and dynamically call the Metadata API's [create](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_create.htm) method.

Here is the example (from the above docs) of the format an Approval Process takes...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApprovalProcess xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <active>false</active>
    <allowRecall>false</allowRecall>
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <type>owner</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <submitter>USSalesRep</submitter>
        <type>role</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <submitter>MarketingGroup</submitter>
        <type>group</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <submitter>kcooper@example.com</submitter>
        <type>user</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
    <approvalPageFields>
        <field>Name</field>
        <field>Owner</field>
        <field>MyLeadCustomField__c</field>
        <field>Address</field>
    </approvalPageFields>
    <approvalStep>
        <allowDelegate>false</allowDelegate>
        <approvalActions>
            <action>
                <name>LeadApprovedTask1</name>
                <type>Task</type>
            </action>
            <action>
                <name>LeadApprovedTask2</name>
                <type>Task</type>
            </action>
        </approvalActions>
        <assignedApprover>
            <approver>
                <type>adhoc</type>
            </approver>
        </assignedApprover>
        <label>Step1</label>
        <name>Step1</name>
        <rejectionActions>
            <action>
                <name>LeadRejectedTask</name>
                <type>Task</type>
            </action>
        </rejectionActions>
    </approvalStep>
    <approvalStep>
        <allowDelegate>false</allowDelegate>
        <assignedApprover>
            <approver>
                <type>userHierarchyField</type>
            </approver>
        </assignedApprover>
        <entryCriteria>
            <criteriaItems>
                <field>Lead.CreatedDate</field>
                <operation>greaterThan</operation>
                <value>3/25/2013</value>
            </criteriaItems>
            <criteriaItems>
                <field>User.IsActive</field>
                <operation>notEqual</operation>
                <value>true</value>
            </criteriaItems>
        </entryCriteria>
        <ifCriteriaNotMet>ApproveRecord</ifCriteriaNotMet>
        <label>Step2</label>
        <name>Step2</name>
        <rejectBehavior>
            <type>RejectRequest</type>
        </rejectBehavior>
    </approvalStep>
    <approvalStep>
        <allowDelegate>true</allowDelegate>
        <assignedApprover>
            <approver>
                <name>MarketingTeamQueue</name>
                <type>queue</type>
            </approver>
            <approver>
                <name>LastModifiedBy</name>
                <type>relatedUserField</type>
            </approver>
            <approver>
                <name>awheeler@example.com</name>
                <type>user</type>
            </approver>
            <whenMultipleApprovers>FirstResponse</whenMultipleApprovers>
        </assignedApprover>
        <entryCriteria>
            <formula>CONTAINS( MyLeadCustomField__c , 'Salesforce')</formula>
        </entryCriteria>
        <label>Step3</label>
        <name>Step3</name>
        <rejectBehavior>
            <type>BackToPrevious</type>
        </rejectBehavior>
    </approvalStep>
    <emailTemplate>MyFolder/LeadsNewassignmentnotification</emailTemplate>
    <enableMobileDeviceAccess>false</enableMobileDeviceAccess>
    <entryCriteria>
        <criteriaItems>
            <field>Lead.AnnualRevenue</field>
            <operation>greaterThan</operation>
            <value>10500</value>
        </criteriaItems>
        <criteriaItems>
            <field>Lead.MyLeadCustomField__c</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>Salesforce</value>
        </criteriaItems>
    </entryCriteria>
    <finalApprovalActions>
        <action>
            <name>LeadEmailContacted</name>
            <type>Alert</type>
        </action>
    </finalApprovalActions>
    <finalApprovalRecordLock>true</finalApprovalRecordLock>
    <finalRejectionActions>
        <action>
            <name>ProcessRejectedMessageAction</name>
            <type>OutboundMessage</type>
        </action>
    </finalRejectionActions>
    <finalRejectionRecordLock>false</finalRejectionRecordLock>
    <initialSubmissionActions>
        <action>
            <name>LeadFieldUpdate</name>
            <type>FieldUpdate</type>
        </action>
        <action>
            <name>NewLeadEmail</name>
            <type>Alert</type>
        </action>
    </initialSubmissionActions>
    <label>SampleProcess</label>
    <nextAutomatedApprover>
        <useApproverFieldOfRecordOwner>false</useApproverFieldOfRecordOwner>
        <userHierarchyField>customlookupuserfield__c</userHierarchyField>
    </nextAutomatedApprover>
    <postTemplate>MyPostTemplate</postTemplate>
    <recallActions>
        <action>
            <name>ProcessRecalledMessageAction</name>
            <type>OutboundMessage</type>
        </action>
    </recallActions>
    <recordEditability>AdminOnly</recordEditability>
    <showApprovalHistory>false</showApprovalHistory>
</ApprovalProcess>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is a really large approval process. As you know there are several options for migrating the approval process. You can use Flosum to accomplish this... it is a replacement to [Force.com migration toolkit.](http://www.flosum.com) Also, it is much easier and powerful compared to changesets and ant migration toolkit.